# How to convert a URI to base64 in angularJS?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a custom file chooser plugin which selects a PDF file from my device once the file is selected i am getting the response as below.I would like to convert the URI to base64 string. Can anyone tell me how to do that in angularJS?

Output Received:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/E0FD-1813%3AVishal%20Ranjan_%20OOPS%20Concept%20With%20Real%20Life%20Example.pdf
```

Code which converts selected PDF:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

if (uri != null) {
    Log.w(TAG, uri.toString());
    callback.success(uri.toString());
} else {
    callback.error("File uri was null");
}
```

Comment: You can use encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Use atob() and btoa() to encode/decode base64 string (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a angularjs factory that encodes and decodes a string with Base64

```
(function(){
'use strict'; 
angular.module('sampleapp')
.factory('Base64', function () {

    var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
    return {
        encode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            do {
                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;

                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }

                output = output +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        },

        decode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
            var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
            if (base64test.exec(input)) {
                window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                    "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                    "Expect errors in decoding.");
            }
            input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

            do {
                enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

                if (enc3 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                }
                if (enc4 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                }

                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        }
    };     
});

})();
```

To use it simply call

```
var string="valueofString";
var authdata = Base64.encode(string);
```

Comment: @F K M N it shows the file path. using the file path is it possible to convert it into base64